# Interbase / Firebird equivalent for mysql_num_rows()

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I'm looking for an efficient way to retrieve a count of the number of rows returned a result set from an Interbase / Firebird DB.

The closest equivalent (but unusable) function that I've found is `mysql_num_rows()`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE mykey > 1
ORDER BY myKey
ROWS 100
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PHP's [PDO library](https://www.php.net/pdo)?